# Best way to export data from other company's SAP

Tags: abap, sap-gui

I need to extract some data from my client's SAP ECC (the SUIM -> Users by Complex Selection Criteria -program RSUSR002)

Normally I give them a table of values that I they have to fill some field to extract what I need.

They have to make 63 different extractions (with different values of objects, for example - but inside the same transaction - you can see in the print) from their SAP, to later send to me all extracted files.

[image: They have to fill these fields]

Do you know if there is an automated way to extract that, so they don't have to make 63 extractions?
My biggest problem is that every time they make mistakes. It's a lot of things to fill..

Can I create a variant and send it to them? Is it possible to export my variant so they can import it without the need to fill 63x different data?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or something they need to do regularly? If the latter, I would look into some way to automatize that data transfer with some ABAP programs. Either by transferring flatfiles or by using an RFC call, depending on what's easier to accomplish with my infrastructure. But for a one-time action that would likely not be worth the effort.

Comment: 1x/Year for each company that uses SAP.
Do you think ABAP programs would be a better way for this kind of extraction?

Comment: I would consult [this table](https://xkcd.com/1205/) to decide that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this is a task which takes considerable effort by multiple people each year, then it is something which might be worth automatizing.

First you need to find out where that transaction gets its data from. If you spend some time analyzing and debugging the program behind the transaction, you will surely find which SELECT's on which database table(s) provide that data. If you are lucky, there might even be a function module for it.

Then you just need to write an own ABAP program which performs the same selections.

Now about the interesting part: How to get that data to you. There are several approaches here. The best one depends on your requirements and your technical infrastructure. Some possibilities are:

- Let users run the program in foreground, use the method `cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_download` to save the data to a file on the user's PC and ask them to send it to you via email
- Run the program in background and save the file on the application server. Then ask your sysadmins how to get that file from their application server to you. The simplest way would be to just map a network fileserver so they all write to the same place, but there might be some organizational hurdles in the way which prevent that. (Our security people would call me crazy if I proposed to allow access to SMB shares from outside of our network, but your mileage may vary)
- Have the program send the data to you directly via email. You can send emails from an SAP system using the function module `SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_ATT_SEND_API1`. This of course requires that the system was configured to be able to send emails (which you can do with transaction code SCOT). Again, security considerations apply. When it's PII or other confidential data, then you should not send it in an unencrypted email.
- Use an RFC call to send the data to your own SAP system which aggregates the data
- Use a webservice call to send the data to your own non-SAP system which aggregates the data

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recording in transaction SM35.
There you fill a tcode (SUIM), start recording, make some input in transaction SUIM and then press 'Execute'. Then you can go back to recording (F3 multiple times) and the system will generate some table with commands (structure is BDCDATA). You can delete unnecessary part (i.e. BACK button click) and save it to use as a 'macro'. Then you can replay this recording and it will do exactly what you did.
Also it's possible to export/import the recording to text file, so you can explore it's structure, write some VBA script to create such recording from your parameters and sent it to users. But keep in mind that blanks are meaningful.

It's a standard tools so there's no any coding in the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the selection as a variant.
Fill in the selection criteria and press Save.
It can be reused.
You can also transport Variants if the they have a special name
[image]